# How to use the Loading Controller with duration

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have my LoadingController :

```
const loader = this.loadCtrl.create({
     content: 'Loading ...',
     duration: 5000
});
loader.present();
```

Just after i have an api call

```
myApi.Function().then(res => {
   console.log(res);
}
```

I want to `dismiss` my LoadingController when my api call is end **OR** if my duration is end.

How can i call the event `loader.dismiss()` after the duration ?

thanks,

Comment: if you use `then` your `Function` must return a promise. if that's not the case, try using `subscribe` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) for that:

> The `Promise.race()` method returns a promise that resolves or rejects
>   as soon as one of the promises in an iterable resolves or rejects,
>   with the value or reason from that promise.

```js
const delayPromise = new Promise(resolve => window.setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000));
const apiPromise = myApi.Function();

const loader = this.loadCtrl.create({
     content: 'Loading ...',
});
loader.present();

Promise.race([delayPromise, apiPromise]).then(res => {
    loader.dismiss();

    if(res) {
        // apiPromise finished first
    } else {
        // delayPromise finished first
    }
});
```